# Cloning an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, clone

The below first logs `0`, and then logs `1`. How do I store a *copy* of the object, rather than a *reference* to it?

```
debug.log(vi.details.segment);
vi.nextSegment = vi.details;
vi.nextSegment.segment++;
debug.log(vi.details.segment);
```

Answer (score 154, accepted):

To clone an object in jQuery:

```
var vi.nextSegment = jQuery.extend({}, vi.details);
```

**NOTE:** The above is a shallow copy: any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference - meaning any changes you make to `vi.nextSegment.obj[prop]` will be reflected in `vi.details.obj[prop]`.  If you want a completely new object which is *completely separate from the original*, you will need to do a deep copy (pass `true` as the first parameter):

```
var vi.nextSegment = jQuery.extend(true, {}, vi.details);
```

To read up more on extend, see [here.](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend)

Comment: That isn't a deep copy. `var a = {b: [1, 2]}; $.extend({}, a).b[0] = 'test';` and `a.b[0]` will be changed to `'test'`. To do a deep copy, put `true` as the first argument: `$.extend(true, {}, a);`

Comment: One gothcha that just got me: `jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);` will create a copy. `jQuery.extend(true, obj, {});` will not.

Comment: @worldsayshi : I wish I saw your comment sooner. Having headaches on this for weeks. Thanks a lot.

Comment: brilliant, guys! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 36):

Take a look at the post: [**What is the most efficient way to clone a javascript object**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

*As per [John Resig's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6524/john-resig) answer:*

```
// Shallow copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);

// Deep copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

More information can be found in the [jQuery documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend)

Answer (score 8):

This worked better for me cloning an object using jQuery "parseJSON()" and "JSON.stringify()"

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    var objY = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
    var objX = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});
```

Cloning data object in objX & objY are two different object, you do no have to mess up with the "by reference" problem

Gracias!

Comment: you could do this without jquery
use JSON.parse built-in method

Answer (score 7):

Another way to clone object is

```
newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj));
```

But be careful if it's contains dates. JSON.parse will return date.toString() instead of date in that case.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I copy elements several times:

First I have a template:

```
<div class="forms-container">
    <div class="form-template">
        First Name <input>
         .. a lot of other data ...
        Last Name <input>
     <div>
     <button onclick="add_another();">Add another!</button>
<div>
```

Now, the JavaScript:

```
function add_another(){
    jQuery(".form-template").clone().appendTo(".forms-container");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Try `Immutable.js` :

Since `jQuery` mostly deals with `DOM Elements`, it *may not* be the right tool for the job.  `Immutable.js` is a `56 kb (minified)` library created by `Facebook`.

```
// roughly implementing
import Immutable from 'immutable'
//
const oldObj = { foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' }
// create a map from the oldObj and then convert it to JS Object
const newObj = Immutable.Map(oldObj).toJS()
```

This way you would have effectively cloned `newObj` from `oldObj`.  Basically, if you don't have a `Map` already, then we need to create a `Map` first. Map is like a `blue-print` that we work with to create `copies`.

#### References :

**Home -** [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

**Docs -** [Immutable Docs](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/)

**GitHub -** [Immutable@GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/)

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep you initial object but need to override your data with your new options, you can pass multiple objects to $.extend (jQuery) with true on first option:

```
var opts_default = {opt1: true, opt2: false};
var opts_new = {opt1: false};
var opts_final = $.extend(true, {}, opts_default, opts_new);
```